# What is the id used for passing into salesforce api via api explorer for various endpoins?

Tags: api, integration

I have successfully created a SalesForce development account where now I am trying to send api requests to several endpoints where I need to pass in an id into the endpoint, what do I use for id, or where do I generate them from to successfully send my first api request for endpoints such as createAccount for example?

**Example request body**

```
{
  "Fax": "string",
  "Name": "string",
  "Type": "string",
  "Phone": "string",
  "Jigsaw": "string",
  "OwnerId": "1",   <----------------------------id I pass in
  "SicDesc": "string",
  "Website": "string",
  "Industry": "string",
  "ParentId": "string",
  "BillingCity": "string",
  "Description": "string",
  "BillingState": "string",
  "ShippingCity": "string",
  "AccountSource": "string",
  "AnnualRevenue": "number",
  "BillingStreet": "string",
  "ShippingState": "string",
  "BillingCountry": "string",
  "ShippingStreet": "string",
  "BillingLatitude": "number",
  "ShippingCountry": "string",
  "BillingLongitude": "number",
  "ShippingLatitude": "number",
  "BillingPostalCode": "string",
  "NumberOfEmployees": "integer",
  "ShippingLongitude": "number",
  "ShippingPostalCode": "string",
  "BillingGeocodeAccuracy": "string",
  "ShippingGeocodeAccuracy": "string"
}
```

**Response from api call**

```
[
  {
    "message": "Cannot deserialize instance of currency from VALUE_STRING value number or request may be missing a required field at [line:16, column:28]",
    "errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
  }
]
```

Comment: what do you mean by ID?

Comment: in my sample request above I pass in OwnerId of 1 but I am unsure of the proper value in the request.  this being for only the single endpoint I use in my example

Comment: /services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Account/1 is the call in api explorer that I use to retrieve my unsuccessfully added account, and I get a response as such:  "Provided external ID field does not exist or is not accessible: 1"

Comment: Id field in SF is auto generated String, you cannot generate it yourself. OwnerId is a user id that owns the record. So if you want to set the owner for the record, you have to know the user id.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are providing incorrect data for a lot of data types. In order to fix it, start with just the Account name first which is the **only required field** (by default, in case your org doesn't have other object level required fields) and you will receive the auto-generated Salesforce Id in a response similar to this -

1) Request Body -

```
{
  "Name": "string"
}
```

2) Response Body -

```
{
  "id" : "0012800001bJz2kAAC",
  "success" : true,
  "errors" : [ ],
  "warnings" : [ ]
}
```

Now you can use this `GET request` to access the newly created Account record using it's id - `/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Account/0012800001bJz2kAAC`. Just to be clear ownerId and id are different and it is looking for the id in this request.

After that you can add in more fields and make sure you are passing the correct data type for each of them. You can use this `GET request` to help you identify the correct data types - `/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Account/describe` and you can find them under fields OR you could manually check the data type in your org instance OR use [Workbench Rest Explorer](https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php) to get it done faster.